# Woocommerce Custom Availability Text in Translation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We want to change the availability text to a custom one and I implemented the following filter inside the functions.php:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    
    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
    }
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Unfortunately the text is not changing. I assume that's because our wordpress site is set to German, the filter here does however only change the original english text? How to change the German text?

Comment: are you using any plugin for translation or multilanguage?

Comment: Nope, we're only using the default translation offered by WP

Comment: In that case, You now need to re-create POT file translate it and create po and mo file and upload it to the same location with the same name of the file will do your work.

Comment: Download the theme into your local machine, use po editor software on your machine and then create po file. Translate that using po editor s/w and create mo file. Make sure the file name should be same as it's on the server. Upload both file at the same location as those are now. It's only think you can get your string translated.

Comment: So filter doesn't work?